# Why is ping failing in subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm getting an error out of `subprocess.Popen()` for a command that works fine on the command line.

The command is a simple:

```
pax> ping -c2 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1:icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1:icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
```

However, when I try to do that from Python (interactive), it acts like I've left off the address:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> import subprocess
>>> args = shlex.split("ping -c2 127.0.0.1") ; print(args)
['ping', '-c2', '127.0.0.1']
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(proc.stdout.read()) ; print(proc.stderr.read())
b''
b'ping: usage error: Destination address required\n'
```

That error message is *exactly* what I get when I try to execute:

```
ping -c2
```

from the shell without an address.

What could be causing this?

Comment: why are you using stdin when you don't need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/env python

import shlex
import subprocess

args = shlex.split("ping -c2 127.0.0.1")
cmdproc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(cmdproc.stdout.read())
```

This is what you could do.  Remove `shell=True` and `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`

This then produces the following:

```
b'PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms\n64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms\n\n--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---\n2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.034/0.043/0.010 ms\n'
```

Further explanation as if you use the `shell=True` argument, according to [1] you need to specify the args as a string, i.e. "ping -c2 127.0.0.1"

And since you aren't requiring to enter anything from stdin, you don't need stdin.

[1] - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

`shell=True` is used when passing the command as a string

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ping -c2 127.0.0.1", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

if passing args as a list then it must be `shell=False`

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("ping -c2 127.0.0.1"), shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

> If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.